# Chromedriver not opening Django development server

Tags: python, django, macos, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I am formulating my first tests with Selenium and Chromedriver. I kept getting a NoSuchElementException in my test results. I tried to using an explicit wait but it timed out. I noticed that Chrome was raising ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND so I made the path more explicit in my driver.get(file_uri()). Chrome found the html but was displaying my pure Django code instead of the generated html. If the development server was being launched properly I believe my test would be passing but I have no idea why it's not functioning as expected.

Here is my test:

```
class WebpageTests(unittest.TestCase):

def test_title(self):
    driver.get(file_uri("network/templates/network/index.html"))
    open_form = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "new-post")))
    open_form.click()
    form = driver.find_element_by_id("post-view")
    self.assertTrue(form.is_displayed())
    
    if __name__ == "__main__":
        unittest.main()
```

here is my setup:

```
from sqlite3 import Timestamp
from xxlimited import foo
from django.test import Client, TestCase
from .models import Post, User
from selenium import webdriver
import os
import pathlib
import unittest 
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def file_uri(filename):
    return pathlib.Path(os.path.abspath(filename)).as_uri()

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: You cannot call driver.get on something like `file:///...`. You should get URI of the form `http://localhost:3000/.../network/templates/network/index.html`

Comment: This is helpful in clarifying the potential source of my problem but as I have defined file_uri as a function that returns the URI should this not be working as you have suggested?

Comment: `pathlib` is for `local path` and `as_uri()` gives uri to `local` file - `file:///...` - but web browser needs uri to `remove` page - and `pathlib` can't create it because it is not for `remote` uri. You will have to create manually this `remote` path - eventually you can use `urllib.parse` for some elements.

Comment: I see. After abandoning use of this function and putting the remote path in driver.get my test is passing. Thank you!